# Using Selenium IDE to act on a Popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have an application that still uses popup windows over Modals, and we need to test the behavior of some of the popups. In my current stage of research it appears the failure occurs on a waitForPopup call. To confirm this, I made a basic HTML page to throw a popup when a link is clicked (easily simulated with IDE)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Popup</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="#" class="click_me" id="click_me" onclick="openwindow();">Click Me</a>
  </body>

  <script>
    function openwindow() {
    var i, l, options = [{
      value: 'first',
      text: 'First'
    }, {
      value: 'second',
      text: 'Second'
    }],
    newWindow = window.open("", "popup1", "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");  

    newWindow.document.write("<select onchange='window.opener.setValue(this.value);'>");
    for(i=0,l=options.length; i<l; i++) {
        newWindow.document.write("<option value='"+options[i].value+"'>");  
        newWindow.document.write(options[i].text);  
        newWindow.document.write("</option>");
    }
    newWindow.document.write("</select>");
    }

    function setValue(value) {
    document.getElementById('value').value = value;
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

And the Selenium test case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://localhost.localdev.com/" />
<title>localpopuptest</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">localpopuptest</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=click_me</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=click_me</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPopUp</td>
    <td>popup1</td>
    <td>30000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertTitle</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Test Popup</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

This seems to be a common issue, is there a better way to track and assert popup windows?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
click        | id=click_me
selectWindow | popup1
select       | //select    | Second
```

If your popup has a dynamic content you can just add:

```
waitForElementPresent | //select
```

**after** selectWindow.